# Basic question about RGB planes

Tags: image-processing

If a 3-bit, 2 × 2 RGB image has the following planes:

[image]

how can we write each plane to a vector of size 3x1?

Comment: Maybe adding some more context would help. What are you trying to achieve? Or is this supposed to be a puzzle?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am trying to transform each plane into YUK space. I have the transformation matrix but to use it I need to multiply it by the vector of each of those R,G and B planes.

Comment: search with keywords like `python (or java, cpp, csharp) rgb to yuv example`, you'll receive tons of refs, e.g. https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/skimage.color/-/rgb2yiq/python-rgb2yiq-function-examples.html

Comment: @V.V.T Thank you. Actually, I want to learn how to do it mannully rathen than coding it as I am practicing to learn the concept. My main point is how to convert each of the above plane to a vector? A vector of 3x1.

Comment: "I am trying to transform each plane into YUK space" -- do you mean each pixel? You can take one number from each of the planes, for example the top-left pixel: (1,1,1), and that's a 3-vector, an RGB value, that you can multiply by your matrix to get a YUK value. (Are you sure it's YUK? I haven't heard of such a color space, and neither has Google.)

Comment: Please don't double-post. This question was also posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67952058/how-to-write-the-rgb-planes-in-the-form-of-3x1-vectors

Comment: @plpm, Could you link to the definition of YUK? I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is not using as yet unconventional terminology of image classification with deep learning tools (and 'YUK' is a typo, you mean YUV), it hardly ever makes sense to talk about color spaces of 1-bit-per-color and even 3-bit-depth images, so we assume that you are looking for an algorithm and data structures used when doing color space conversion with typical color images like 24- or 32-bit-color-depth raster images.

You do not specify the computer language of your choice, so let us examine the Python code implementing a color space conversion algorithm. Python language is widely used in this forum, quite similar to MATLAB scripts, and I wrote this sample in a way that you would be able to readily translate it to C-like languages. Python's comprehensive online documentation enables you to understand the program even if you do not code in this language.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.image
import matplotlib.pyplot
import cv2

img = matplotlib.image.imread('rgbimage.png')
rgbimg = matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(img)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()

rgbdata = rgbimg.get_array()
# we use only RGB components so slice component number to 3 excluding color component ALPHA
rgbdata = rgbdata[:,:,0:3]

#  BT.470 System M color space conversion matrix from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV
RGB2YUV = numpy.array([0.299, 0.587, 0.114,
                      -0.14713, -0.28886, 0.436,
                      0.615, -0.51499, -0.10001
                      ])
RGB2YUV = RGB2YUV.reshape(3,3)

# initialize array for YUV image data
yuvdata = numpy.full(numpy.shape(rgbdata), 0.0)

# one-liner for RGB-to-YUV conversion
# notice the value 0.5 (128 if datatype is UINT) added to Cb, Cr (U,V) color components
yuvdata[:,:] = rgbdata[:,:].dot(RGB2YUV.T) + [0.0, 0.5, 0.5]

# restore RGB data with opencv to make sure our manual rgb2yuv conversion is correct
yuvdatatyped = yuvdata.astype("float32")
rgbrestored = cv2.cvtColor(yuvdatatyped, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)
cv2.imshow('BGR', rgbrestored)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You would not find `a vector of size 3x1` in this code sample; most close thing to this 'vector' is in the line

```
yuvdata[:,:] = rgbdata[:,:].dot(RGB2YUV.T) + [0.0, 0.5, 0.5]
```

which, conveniently expressed as a matrix operation, has the form
$$
\text {YUV[i,j] = RGB[i,j]} * \text {RGB2YUV}^T + \text {const}
$$
where $\text {YUV}$ (`yuvdata`) is a pixel array of YUV-color-space triplets $[Y, U, V]$ and $\text {RGB}$ (`rgbdata`) is a pixel array of RGB-color-space triplets $[R, G, B]$. Values $Y, U, V, R, G, B$ are floats varying in the range [0.0, 1.0);  $\text {RGB2YUV}^T$ is a transposed color space conversion matrix $\text {RGB2YUV}$ for an RGB-to-YUV transformation, $\text {const} = [0, 0.5, 0.5]$ is an adjustment for $U,V (Cb,Cr)$ components.

You see that the most close thing to "a vector of size 3x1" is a triplet `[R,G,B]` attached to every pixel of your RGB image, provided that you allow for 'a vector of size 3x8' or 3xFloat to represent the color of image pixels. You need not construct these triplets in the code, for these are readily available in the RGB pixel array that you read from the image file with the I/O operation `img = matplotlib.image.imread('rgbimage.png')`.

Notice that the imports for `numpy` and `matplotlib` are standard for Python installations. Only the namespace cv2 in `import cv2` requires some additional effort of installing the opencv-python package. I added the lines requiring this package only for independent verification of our "manual" RGB->YUV conversion result. The lines `yuvdatatyped = yuvdata.astype("float32")` and `rgbrestored = cv2.cvtColor(yuvdatatyped, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)`transform our YUV pixel data back to an RGB color space using the opencv package functions. The line `cv2.imshow('BGR', rgbrestored)` draws the restored image to the screen for visual comparison.

Of course, you can use the opencv functions for the RGB-to-YUV conversion, and it is the recommended way to perform the conversion operations.

Comment: Thank you very much.